# Querying in mongoose and filtering by dates

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this levels in mongoose documents [image]

I'm trying to make a filter to populate the geometry for the locations that are in the range of some date.

I try something like this:

```
.populate('geometries', null, { 'locations.properties.timeStamp': { $gt: startDate, $lt: endDate }})
.exec(function(err, item) {
//some code
}
```

And like this:

```
 .populate('geometries')
 .where({ 'locations.properties.timeStamp': { $gt: startDate, $lt: endDate }}*/)
 .exec(function(err, item) {
    //some code
    }
```

With these query I can not access the timeStamp to compare, and the result is null or undefined.

**EDIT 1:**

The variables, startDate and endDate comes in the url from angulars controller, they are defined like this:

```
            var deductDate = new Date(endDate);
            var startDate = deductDate.setDate(deductDate.getDate()-1);

            Item.currentDay($stateParams.epc, url, {
                groupBy: '1d',
                endDate: moment(endDate).format(),
                startDate: moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T23:59:59"
            });
```

And in the API the GET route that handles that is:

```
 handler: function(request, reply) {
  var startDate = request.query.startDate;
  var endDate = request.query.endDate;
  Item.findById(request.params.id)
    .populate('geometries', null, { 'locations.properties.timeStamp': { $gt: startDate, $lt: endDate }})
    .exec(function(err, item) {
      if (err) {
        reply(err);
      } else {
        reply(item);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show us where you're defining startDate and endDate

Comment: Thanks for your answer @YuriZarubin, in the original post a add what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
.populate({
  path: 'geometries',
  match: { 'locations.properties.timeStamp': { $gt: startDate, $lt: endDate    }},
}).exec()
```

Extracted from mongoose documentation about Query conditions and other options (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Thanks scuencag, but still not working, the console.log shows null value. This are te format of the days that I'm using to do the search:  startDate: 2015-03-13T23:59:59, endDate: 2015-03-14T19:47:37-03:00. Are they ok?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
  var startDate = new Date(request.query.startDate);
  var endDate = new Date(request.query.endDate);
```

Comment: with that the filter still don't work, is 'locations.properties.timeStamp' correct to acces timeStamp to use the date filter?

Comment: Looks right. Try doing a simple test such as: populate('geometries', null, { 'locations.properties.timeStamp': { $gt: new Date('2015-05-10') }})

Comment: I make that test but the filter not work, returns a null value.